# MySQL REGEXP alnum matching issue

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following string-

> I know what thatÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s like when an army is defeated.

This MySQL command returns 1.

```
select "I know what thatÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s like when an army is defeated." REGEXP '[^[:punct:] A-Za-z0-9]'
```

But, when I use 'alnum' instead of [A-Za-z0-9], it returns 0.

```
select "I know what thatÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s like when an army is defeated." REGEXP '[^[:punct:] [:alnum:]]'
```

Can anyone please explain the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`HEX(CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT("Ã¢â‚¬â„¢s" USING latin1)) USING utf8))` -> `C3A2E282ACE284A273` -> `â€™s` (when utf8)

`CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT("â€™s" USING latin1)) USING utf8)` -> `’s`

So you have `that's` with a funny apostrophe, possibly from Microsoft Word?  Furthermore it is "double encoded".

If your REGEXP trying to find 8-bit codes for further analysis, consider:

```
HEX(col) RLIKE '^(..)*(0[012345678BCEF]|7F|[189ABCDEF].)'
```

Then, if you want to 'fix' the double encoding, [see my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).  Let me know if you need help picking out the parts you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand how "’s" got end up like that but I could not understand why alnum and [A-Za-z0-9] behaved differently.